# Arbol binario para calcular operaciones simples

Tags: java

[image: Arbol binario de operaciones]

Este árbol representa la siguiente operacion lógica :

`(((5 + 3) / 2) + ((1 - 5) * 2))`

Alguien sabe cómo calcularlo? Se puede usar cualquier estructura de datos yo he usado la siguiente:

```
public class Elem{
   char operacion;
   int numero;
   boolean esOperacion;
}
public class Nodo{
   Elem contenido;
   Nodo izq;
   Nodo der;
   Nodo padre;
}
public class ArbolBinario{
   Nodo raiz;
   public int calcular(){
      return(calcular(0,root));
   }
   private int calcular(int resultado, Nodo a){
       if(a == null){
          return(resultado);
       }else if(a.esOperacion){
            if(a.left != null && a.rigth != null){
                if(operacion.equals('+'){
                    return(calcular(resultado,a.izq) + calcular(resultado, a.der);
                }else if(operacion.equals('-'){
                    return(calcular(resultado,a.izq) - calcular(resultado, a.der);
                }else if(operacion.equals('*'){
                    return(calcular(resultado,a.izq) * calcular(resultado, a.der);
                }else{
                    return(calcular(resultado,a.izq) / calcular(resultado, a.der);
                }
              //POR AQUI SEGUIRIA PERO ESTOY BASTANTE SEGURO DE QUE HAY FORMAS MEJORES DE HACERLO O DE QUE ESTA MAL
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Unail. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir lo que has **intentado** hasta ahora y por que no te funcionó: errores, resultado  no esperado, problemas ... mira [ask]  para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: No llegue a acabar el codigo ademas lo tengo escrito en papel. El problema simplemente es que no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo ni siquiera en papel lo tengo acabado.

Comment: Pues has de intentarlo para que podamos indicarte qué hiciste mal o como mejorarlo. Sin haberlo intentado es una pregunta muy amplia.

Comment: porque estas seguro que esta mal? no anda? si es asi, que error obtienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaría una estructura distinta, definiendo una interfaz `Nodo` común, con 2 implementaciones. Una que representa un número, y la otra que representa una operación aritmética:

```
public interface Nodo {}

public class NumeroNodo implements Nodo {
    public int numero;
}

public class OperacionNodo implements Nodo {
    public char operacion;
    public Nodo expresionIzquierda;
    public Nodo expresionDerecha;
}
```

Con esta estructura, la lógica recursiva para hacer el cáclulo a partir de la raíz de un árbol de nodos es bien sencilla:

```
public int calcular(Nodo nodo) {
    if (nodo instanceof NumeroNodo) {
        return ((NumeroNodo)nodo).numero;
    } else {
        OperacionNodo operacionNodo = (OperacionNodo)nodo;
        int valorIzquierda = calcular(operacionNodo.expresionIzquierda);
        int valorDerecha = calcular(operacionNodo.expresionDerecha);

        switch(operacionNodo.operacion) {
            case '+':
                return valorIzquierda + valorDerecha;
            case '-':
                return valorIzquierda - valorDerecha;
            case '*':
                return valorIzquierda * valorDerecha;
            case '/':
                return valorIzquierda / valorDerecha;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Operación inválida: " + operacionNodo.operacion);
        }
    }
}
```

Toma en cuenta que al usar el tipo `int` para manipular los valores, todas las operaciones aritméticas van a perder las partes fraccionales de los cáclulos si las hay, y puede acabar dándote un resultado inesperado. Para evitar este problema, puedes mas bien usar un `float` o un `double` en todos los lugares donde tienes un `int`.